# Mobile Advertising - Targeting ads based on a map (Huyundai) - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, mobile, us20130132198, huyundai

**AN OVERBROAD PATENT ON targeting mobile ads based on a map** - This application from [Huyundai](http://www.hyundaiusa.com) seeks to patent the idea of...an advertisement server providing ads to users in a geographic region based on a map! 10 minutes of your time can help narrow US patent applications before they become patents.  [Follow @askpatents](https://twitter.com/AskPatents) on twitter to help.

**QUESTION** - Have you seen anything that was **published before 5/15/2009** that discusses:

> - specifying a "region of interest" on a map and targeting ads to users who go there

If so, please submit evidence of prior art as an answer to this question. We welcome multiple answers from the same individual.

**EXTRA CREDIT** - A reference to anything that meets all of the criteria to the question above AND ALSO uses time of day or text of the advertisement to decide whether to display ads

**TITLE: Embedded map with dedicated advertising region**

**Summary**:  [Translated from Legalese into English] A system using a map which targets ads based on a region of interest on the map and location of users

- **Publication Number**: [US20130132198 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130132198?dq=US20130132198A1)
- **Application Number**: US 13/618,188
- **Assignee**: Huyundai
- **Prior Art Date**: Seeking prior Art **predating** 5/15/2009
- **Open for Challenge at USPTO:** Open through 11/19/2013

**Claim 1** requires each and every step below:

> An advertisement system using an embedded map, the system comprising:
>
> 1. A space of interest (SOI) server for generating location based data using an SOI object; and
> 2. An advertisement server for providing advertisement content information to an advertisement region of the embedded map using the location based data.

In English this means:

> An advertisement system which uses an embedded map, comprising
>
> 1. An "SOI" server which manages location information for the user; and
> 2. An advertisement server which provides ad information to the dedicated advertising region of the embedded map

Good prior art would be evidence of a system that did each and every one of these steps prior to 5/15/2009

You're probably aware of ten pieces of art that meet this criteria already... separately, the applicant is claiming using time of day or text of advertisement to targeted ads to specific "spaces of interest" on a map

---

**"Embedded map with dedicated advertising region from the Applicant"**

[image]

---

*What is good prior art? Please see our [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).*

*Want to help? Please vote or comment on submissions below. We welcome you to [post your own request for prior art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request+pre-grant) on other questionable US Patent Applications.*

---

Answer (score 6):

This [Google Adwords blog post](http://adwords.blogspot.ca/2005/11/use-google-maps-to-target-your.html) from November 21, 2005 describes how to select a region of interest for targeted ads by selecting a location on an embedded map (and defining a radius). Google will then serve targeted ads to users from that region.

Answer (score 2):

May I point out that "region of interest" could very well be a country. Here is an example from [Admob](http://www.scribd.com/doc/3143695/AdMob-iMedia-Agency-Summit-May-2008) that states that they can target mobile ads on country (p.44)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Polish company offering location-based advertisements in public transport:
https://www.geoadvert.pl/

They display advertisements in buses equipped with a GPS device.

Comment: Is there any way to date this: "Seeking prior Art predating 5/15/2009"